# Buddypress ajax latest messages

Tags: message, buddypress

I am using the following code to display latest message in a template. This works great however it requires a page refresh to update.

[images latest messages](http://www.taraj.sk/zaklad-header-sparvy1-vrch.jpg)

```
<?php if ( bp_has_message_threads('per_page=3') ) : ?>

<?php while ( bp_message_threads() ) : bp_message_thread(); ?>

<?php if ( bp_message_thread_has_unread() ) : ?> <?php else: ?> <?php endif; ?>

<?php bp_message_thread_avatar() ?>

<?php bp_message_thread_from() ?>

<a href="<?php bp_message_thread_view_link() ?>#send-reply">

<img src="/images/odpovedat.png" alt="reply">

</a>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else: ?>

<?php endif;?>
```

The main purpose of this script is to display latest unread messages and it should update via ajax means if user receive any message, latest unread messages without reloading page.